# Python: mapper function argument doesn't take effect when passing the Rename method to a DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, methods

I am relatively beginner with Python programming language.

I have a dataframe defined as the following:

```
Record1 = pd.Series({'Type':'Fork', 'Material':'metal'}) 
Record2 = pd.Series({'Type':'Knife','Material':'Plastic'}) 
Record3 = pd.Series({'Type':'Spoon','Material':'wood'})

S = pd.DataFrame([Record1,Record2,Record3])
```

I try to apply it the `rename` method, with a mapper function intended to cast all the characters into uppercase:

```
S.rename(mapper = lambda x:x.upper(), axis = 1, inplace = True)
```

I expected to get the following dataframe with all its strings transformed to uppercase:

```
    TYPE    MATERIAL
0   Fork    metal
1   Knife   Plastic
2   Spoon   wood
```

But when I type S after having applied the mapper function, I still get it with lowercase characters.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: try without inplace `S=S.rename(mapper = lambda x:x.upper(), axis = 1)`

Comment: I cannot reproduce, running your code with `inplace=True` turns the names of columns uppercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rename()` `lambda` expression is manipulating the column headers, but not the values. Check this by using `S.columns` before and after the call to `rename()`.

```
S.applymap(lambda x : x.capitalize())
```

This will manipulate the values not the column headers.